# How to handle event of item and tab in action bar with custom layout in android?

Tags: tabs, android-actionbar, action

I have three layouts:
 1. calculate_actionbar_layout.xml
 2. purchasingmanager_actionbar_layout.xml
 3. usermanagement_layout.xml

When I select a tab from action bar the relate layout for this tab with item show in action bar. I want handle the event of items in action bar.for example when I click  plus icon do a operation.

this is MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements             
TabListener,OnPageChangeListener,OnClickListener {

ViewPager viewpager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

viewpager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
viewpager.setAdapter(new customefragmentAdapterPager(getSupportFragmentManager()));
viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
actionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionbar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
actionbar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
actionbar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
actionbar.setCustomView(R.layout.usermanagement_layout);

ImageView i=(ImageView) getActionBar().getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.imageviewadduser);
i.setOnClickListener(this);

ActionBar.Tab tab1=actionbar.newTab();
tab1.setTabListener(this);
tab1.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_tab);
View v=tab1.getCustomView();
TextView t=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tab_title);
t.setText("محاسبه");

ActionBar.Tab tab2=actionbar.newTab();
tab2.setText("خریدها");
tab2.setTabListener(this);

ActionBar.Tab tab3=actionbar.newTab();
tab3.setText("کاربران");
tab3.setTabListener(this);

actionbar.addTab(tab1);
actionbar.addTab(tab2);
actionbar.addTab(tab3);

}


}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
    switch (tab.getPosition()) {
    case 0:

        actionbar.setCustomView(R.layout.calculate_actionbar_layout);

        break;
    case 1:

        actionbar.setCustomView(R.layout.purchasingmanager_actionbar_layout);
        break;
    case 2:
        actionbar.setCustomView(R.layout.usermanagement_layout);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return 3;
}}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
int id=v.getId();

int d=id;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub


if(item.getItemId() == R.id.imageviewadduser){
    // ( 1 ) add a new item 
        // ( 2 ) change add to remove
}
else{
        // if a the new item is clicked show "Toast" message.
}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

all layouts have this template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#0d93d2"
android:weightSum="4"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
tools:context="MainActivity"
>
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageviewusermanagment"
android:layout_width="0sp"
android:layout_weight="2.5"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/usermanagment"
android:scaleType="fitStart"
android:paddingLeft="20sp"

 />
 <ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageviewdeleteuser"
android:layout_width="0sp"
android:layout_weight=".5"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/deleteuser"

 />



<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageviewedituser"
android:layout_width="0sp"
android:layout_weight=".5"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/edituser"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageviewadduser"
android:layout_width="0sp"
android:layout_weight=".5"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/adduser"
     />

</LinearLayout>
```

and images of selected tab with different icon that I want to handle event of them. You can see them in below links  :

1. [selected usermanagement_layout.xml for custom action bar](http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-11/44513679731828687914.png)
2. [selected purchasingmanager_actionbar_layout.xml for custom actionbar](http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-11/41457030169772527815.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-  change this function :

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
    View cView=null;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    switch (tab.getPosition()) {
    case 0:

         cView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.calculate_actionbar_layout, null);
         cView.setLayoutParams(param);
         actionbar.setCustomView(cView);

        //actionbar.setCustomView(R.layout.calculate_actionbar_layout);

        break;
    case 1:

        cView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.purchasingmanager_actionbar_layout, null);
        cView.setLayoutParams(param);
        actionbar.setCustomView(cView);

        //actionbar.setCustomView(R.layout.purchasingmanager_actionbar_layout);
        break;
    case 2:
         cView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.usermanagement_layout, null);
         cView.setLayoutParams(param);
        actionbar.setCustomView(cView);

        //actionbar.setCustomView(R.layout.usermanagement_layout);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}
```

2- add  android:onClick="onClick" to each imageview in layout
3- change mainactivity to this
View userView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.usermanagement_layout, null);

```
    ImageView adduser=(ImageView) userView.findViewById(R.id.imageviewadduser);
    adduser.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageView deleteuser=(ImageView) userView.findViewById(R.id.imageviewdeleteuser);
    deleteuser.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageView edituser=(ImageView) userView.findViewById(R.id.imageviewedituser);
    edituser.setOnClickListener(this);
```